# calculator with list box items not mowing the dash when gettin results down in list box (lined up answers)

Tags: c#, loops, listbox, formatting

my problem is :

```
    if (x <= y)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("======================");
        listBox1.Items.Add("|  integer  |  Factorial      |");
        listBox1.Items.Add("======================");
        while (x <= y)
        {  if (x % 2 == 0)
            {
              int f = x;
              int factor = 1;
              while (f != 0)
             { factor = factor * f;
                    f = f - 1; }

                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add("|   " + x + "    |  " + factor + "  |  ");
                }
            }
            x++;
        }
    }
```

in the listbox1 when i get all the answers(they are outputed from top to bottom its OK), the answers in faktor column (also from top to down) moves
the dashes, i need lines with answers, that have less digits to move the dash 
away to line up with the line, which answer has more digits. so it looked like.
border made of dash.

Comment: My eyes. What language is this? Your tags won't get this any exposure (which maybe is for the best given the formatting).

Comment: this is C# simple...thanks for the tag advice.